Why divide probabilities when calculating conditional probability, when we can just divide the cardinalities?
So the "conventional" formula, if we could call it that, for calculating the probability of an event A occurring, given the event B has already occured is:
$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$
Now I've been trying to figure out how this formula is derived intuitively, and here's my line of thinking:
Since we know that B has already occurred, the sample space is restricted to the number of elements in, or the cardinality of B. And in order to calculate the probability of A and B occurring, given that the event B has occurred, we can simply divide the number of elements in $A \cap B$ with the number of elements in B. And here's where my confusion lies. Why does the conventional formula divide the probabilites, rather than just diving the cardinalities of these two events, since we get the same result anyways?

(1) Conventional formula issuing known numbers to derive unknown numbers. Hence that formula makes sense (2) We can use Cardinalities when those are the known numbers, no worries there. (3) We may not have the Cardinalities in general , Eg when Sample Space is Integers / rationals / reals involving infinities. (4) In Contrast , Probability values are always between $0$ & $1$ , not involving infinities.

The "dividing cardinalities" only works when all events are equally likely. The "dividing probabilities" version is a generalization that works in all situations, even when some events are more or less likely than others.

There are two outcomes to the lottery.  You win or you lose.  You don't win with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ though, so cardinalities is irrelevant.
